# Arabic language on froyo?

Tags: java, android, locale

I've got an arabic translation for my application. It works on gingerbread and above, but on froyo some strange letters show up.

Is arabic language even supported on froyo? See example below:

[image: Gingerbread or up ...] **Gingerbread**

**VS**

[image: Froyo] **Froyo**

I have a feeling that the second is not the same as first :)

Comment: It's a different font but the letters appear to correspond. Unfortunately I don't know arabic so I can't be sure.

Comment: @hexafraction You're right. The letters are the same, but on froyo they are not connected (Nobody would actually write like that).

Comment: @Ahmad Not all fonts include such detailed kerning and ligature work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is arabic language even supported on froyo?

AFAIK it's officially supported from Gingerbread on. So, no.

> I have a feeling that the second is not the same as first :)

Well, depends. It's definitely not a joy to read, since the characters on Froyo are not connected with each other (but they *are* the same letters).

Comment: Thank you. So you can actually read those letters? What is your advice about arabic translation on froyo? Should I use it or just leave it in english?

Comment: Yes I can read them, but it's hard if the letters are unconnected. In my opinion it would be better, if you would only provide the arabic translation to devices with Gingerbread and above and leave it to english in froyo and below. Fortunately not many people use froyo ([source](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html)), so it shouldn't be a big deal :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about froyo but if you are seeing strange letters then it means the encoding is not properly set. Try to find and set the encoding to `UTF-8` for froyo.